# Deleting items in a zip array

Tags: arrays, ruby

In the code below:

```
array_1 = ["E", "F", "B", "A"]
array_2 = ["E", "F", "B", "E"]

zip_array = array_1.zip(array_2)
zip_array.each { |array| zip_array.delete(array) if array.uniq.length == 1 }
zip_array # => [["F", "F"], ["E", "A"]]
```

why is `["F", "F"]` not deleted as well? Its `uniq.length` should be `1`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Try changing `...{ |array| zip.array....` to `...{ |array| puts "array=#{array}"; zip_array...`. That will show you what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the first element part-way through the iteration will mean that it skips the next. Try `delete_if`.

```
array_1 = ["E", "F", "B", "A"]
array_2 = ["E", "F", "B", "E"]

zip_array = array_1.zip(array_2)
zip_array.delete_if { |array| array.uniq.length == 1 }

print zip_array
```

Comment: It might be clearer to write: `zip_array.delete_if { |e1,e2| e1==e2 }`. Readers: [Array#delete_if](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if) is the same as `Array#reject!`.